# What is the datatype required for the IN keyword

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a function in PostgreSQL that uses the keyword `IN`. For example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.value IN (1,2,23,5,123 ...etc)
```

I would like to make the part after the `IN` a function argument. However I don't know what the data type is for this. I've looked at the data type in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype.html), but couldn't figure it out.

Complete example:

```
create function testing(test_value ???) returns SETOF test
    stable
    language sql
as
$$
SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.value IN test_value
$$;

alter function testing(???) owner to postgres;
```

Comment: you can pass [table row as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811093/how-to-pass-multiple-rows-to-postgresql-function) and use it like `where test.value in (select value from functionparameternamehere)`

Comment: As for the data type itself the type within the IN list must match the data type of the test variable. So if test variable is integer then the IN list must be integers, if test variable is date then list must be dates, etc. As @a_horse_with_no_name indicates you can use an array of elements but the data type of each array element must match the data type of the test variable.

Comment: Yup, I figured the datatypes inside the brackets should be the same datatype, but I just didn't know what datatype the brackets represented. I first thought that this was a simple datatype like an array, but this was incorrect. I still don't know if it is even a datatype or not, but the answer givin did work. @Belayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array and use the `ANY` operator (the condition `IN (...)` is being converted to = ANY(array[...])` by the optimizer anyway).

```
create function testing(test_values int[]) returns SETOF test
    stable
    language sql
as
$$
SELECT * FROM test WHERE test.value = any(test_values)
$$;
```

Then use it like this:

```
select *
from testing(array[1,2,3,4]);
```